# MouseUp on the Panel?

Tags: .net, winforms

I created a new `WinForm`.
In that WinForm I put a `Panel`. Dock = Fill.

Run the project.
**DoubleClicked on the form's header (to maximize)**

Obtain a mouseUp on the panel:

> Function: WindowsApplication1.Form1.Panel1_MouseUp(Object,
>   System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs), Thread: 0x2068 Main Thread

Is it a bug or a feature? ))

I understand that when I doubleclick some portion of the panel came for a moment under the mouse, but I do not any mouseUp on the panel, however?!

My problem:
I have in my panel some objects that can be selected or not.
When I Click (MouseUp) on the panel (on a "empty" space, free of objets), normally, I unselect all objects.

But in the maximisation case I should leave the objects selection unchanged!

How can I "filter" the maximization case of MouseUp?

Comment: Tomer W is right. But maybe you can first look for an MouseDown event on the panel? Because there is no mouseUp without an mouseDown?

Comment: MouseUp is specific, because opens the context menu, and I need to use some checks inside...

Comment: :) Like your attitude to GUI .. 0ld-5ch00l
fast edit One click menus ?

Answer (score 2):

well you described it perfectly

1. MouseDown on Title
2. MouseUp on Title
3. MouseDown on Title
4. WINDOW IS MAXIMIZED, now the mouse is on the form.
5. MouseUp on FORM.

Even though you are correct, and this behavior is very annoying and useless,
this is how it should logically be.

i recommend to avoid MouseDown/MouseUp as much possible.
use MouseClick/DblClick whenever possible.

Regards,

EDIT:

I have two ideas for you:

**Keep track of MouseUp without MouseDown.**

```
private bool bMouseDownState = false;

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bMouseDownState = true;
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!bMouseDownState)
        return;
    bMouseDownState = false;
}
```

**Notice Maximize event and disregard following MouseUp.**

But this one is trickier when the window is Almost maximized (which wont cause Mouse up!)

and finally disregard a following mouse up (to deselect objects).

**One last - why invent the wheel ? **
Use a already made drawing canvas (visio?)

Comment: see my update. Unfortunately, I can't use MouseClick in my case

Comment: Why does second MouseDown invoke the DoubleClick event, and not the second MouseUp?

Comment: Mouse Click is defined by the MouseDown event, and in some situations confirmed by the MouseUp on the same location...
e.g. mouseDown on an desktop icon generally feels like selecting it (Considering the focus is on the desktop ofcourse)...